# Why does PATINDEX behave differently for VARCHAR and NVARCHAR input when matching/excluding caret/circumflex "^" itself?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, patindex

I have difficulties trying to understand the behavior of PATINDEX when matching the caret symbol "^". I am both using it in it's exclusionary function, and matching it itself. I am trying different combinations of varchar and nvarchar for match pattern and input. The results are not what I expect. I could not find helpful info online.

Sample code, run on SQL Server 2019, collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS:

```
    -- Using patindex to match carets and non-carets confuses me. 
    -- I expect no matches, all results should be zero, 
    -- but only the first field returns a zero, the others get ones/find matches.
    SELECT
       'match_^__v_v'     = PATINDEX(  '^[^^]%',  '^^Z' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
      ,'match_^__v_nv'    = PATINDEX(  '^[^^]%', N'^^Z' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
      ,'match_^__nv_nv'   = PATINDEX( N'^[^^]%', N'^^Z' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
      ,'match_^__nv_v'    = PATINDEX( N'^[^^]%',  '^^Z' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
    
    -- Same issues for this attempt with additional square brackets, 
    -- with the same unexpected results as above:
    SELECT
       'match_[^]__v_v'   = PATINDEX(  '[^][^^]%',  '^^Z' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
      ,'match_[^]__v_nv'  = PATINDEX(  '[^][^^]%', N'^^Z' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
      ,'match_[^]__nv_nv' = PATINDEX( N'[^][^^]%', N'^^Z' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
      ,'match_[^]__nv_v'  = PATINDEX( N'[^][^^]%',  '^^Z' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
    
    -- Similar operation for "normal" letter shows none of the issues. 
    -- All fields return zero, as expected.
    SELECT
       'match_a__v_v'     = PATINDEX(  'a[^a]%',  'aaZ' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
      ,'match_a__v_nv'    = PATINDEX(  'a[^a]%', N'aaZ' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
      ,'match_a__nv_nv'   = PATINDEX( N'a[^a]%', N'aaZ' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
      ,'match_a__nv_v'    = PATINDEX( N'a[^a]%',  'aaZ' COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS)
```

Questions:

1. There should be no match, all fields should get zero. Why are the results not as expected?
2. Why is PATINDEX's behavior different for varchar and nvarchar?
3. Where exactly should I use varchar and/or nvarchar? Should I simply make match pattern and input the same type?

Clearly this has to do with the special function of the caret symbol. What am I missing?

I added COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS, after learning about the significance of the relationship of collation and data type, and after the provided sql fiddle in the comments. Thanks @Martin-Smith and @Thom-A! This makes all formulas with carets fail the same way.

I found pointers to a workaround [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206481/matching-a-closing-square-bracket-with-patindex-using-the-wildcard/206482#206482). This gets a zero, as expected. It uses a binary collation for exact matches by ASCII code and a range within the square brackets. The range can be defined with the same character as first and last. The meaning of the square brackets is [not the characters between ^ and ^].

```
SELECT "match_nv_nv" = PATINDEX( N'^[^^-^]%', N'^^Z' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2)
```

Comment: No repro in the first query. I get 1 for everything *as expected*. All patterns look for a `^` that's not followed by `^`. All strings have such a character

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated (the one you are using *is* deprecated). Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use T-SQL's identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: The supplied code is using the U+005E Circumflex code point (^). Are you actually using that in your test code? You mention _Caret_ in your question which is an entirely different code point, U+2038 (‸), which would render differently in character literals versus National character literals.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - the term "caret" is widely used for the character that has special significance in LIKE. (`^`) Including in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Ignore me, @AlwaysLearning , I had the literals the other way round n my head; that's what I get for answering a call while testing...

Comment: I haven't looked in detail at this Q but you are using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and [SQL Server collations use different comparison rules for non-Unicode and Unicode data, you see different results for comparisons of the same data, depending on the underlying data type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16#SQL-collations)

Comment: I can repro; the behaviour does differ between `SQL...CP1` and non: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jW5RCj-B)

Comment: Thank you, @Martin-Smith, thats a helpful hint! Still confused, though. Looking into this...

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, @Thom-A! Using collation Latin1_GENERAL_CI_AS throughout, You get consistent unexpected results for all formulas using the caret symbol. I am beginning to understand the relationship of collation and data type using PATINDEX. Still confused about the unexpected matches...

Comment: @ThomA At a guess there is anyway some sort of bug going on here, because if you use a `^` inside `[]` it can only have the meaning "exclude" unless you escape it, which you can't do with `PATINDEX`. I think this is better migrated on [dba.se], there are official SQL Server tech people there.